# PHP, Ajax ,Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im new to Php and want to make ajax call to Php file, Php file contains the sql query like below.

```
"SELECT count(*) as noOfReg, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(register_on) as register_on FROM `XXXXX'    GROUP BY current_status, date(register_on)"
```

it will give two values  (noOfReg,register_on). i want to send array to ajax success like below , because i want to use it in charts.

```
[
    [register_on,noOfReg],
    [register_on,noOfReg],
    [register_on,noOfReg],
    [register_on,noOfReg]
]
```

Note:(register_on)--->typically date.

Comment: convert the response to array and then json_encode it

Comment: @Cerlin Boss ,Yes it worked  "convert the response to array and then json_encode it" thank u Cerlin.

Comment: Something like this , if any one wants  $a = array((int)$row['register_on'],(int)$row['noofregistraitons']);
                  
                       echo json_encode($a);

Answer (score 0):

- [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)
- http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/04/ajax-add-delete-sql-records-jquery-php
- http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/

Comment: Links can be posted as comments too, they don't need to be answers.